# Convert ObjectID to String in Springboot mongo Aggregation

Tags: string, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, objectid

I have a query:

```
db.results.aggregate([{
        $project: {
            "_id": {
                $toString: "$_id"
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

I need to convert this into java springboot aggregation. I'm confused with $toString in java.

Any idea?

Comment: please paste your aggregation code. Also, `ObjectId.toString()` ?

Comment: Change $project to $addFields.

Comment: how $addFields will work?

Answer (score 2):

In Spring aggregation you need to use like below which give a String value of ObjectId:

```
ProjectionOperation projectOp = Aggregation.project().andArrayOf(new Document("$toString","$_id")).as("id");
```